# I would like to know how it is possible for JavaScript to make the variable visible on click

Tags: variables, onclick

```
function myx() {
    document.getElementById('poo').style.cssText = 'border-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);color: black;font-size: 20px;padding: 0px;margin: 10px 20px';
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "8300$" (I would like a variable instead of 8300$, like demo + 300)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

U can use a template literal (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
Example:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `${demo}300$`;
```